# GPS observational error on MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

guys.

I'm trying to create MapView, where current location of device shows as pin in center of screen. That's works pretty good. I want to add GPS [observational error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_error) (not sure how it is called on English, sorry) circle around the pin.  Saw this feature in one iOS application. Is there any ways to realize this on Android?

Comment: Are you referring to Location accuracy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of what you are trying to do [here](https://gist.github.com/950256). Hope this helps.